# Axios vs jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js, axios

Изучаю Vue.js и потребовался асинхронный запрос на сервер... До этого пользовался всегда Ajax'ом от jQuery, но недавно наткнулся на Axios. Нигде нет плюсов и минусов этих библиотек и прошу вашего совета: что лучше в совокупности с Vue.js? Где больше/меньше нагрузки на сервер при постоянных запросах и тд

Comment: Axios существенно компактнее jQuery. Это все объективные преимущества в сравнении с jQuery. По нагрузке разницы нет. Субъективно Axios с Vue удобнее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) - это универсальная библиотека и может использоваться и с node.js и в браузере. axios - [реализует](https://github.com/axios/axios#promises) правильный современный [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). axios поддерживает ES6 и легко интегрируется с Vuе на этапе разработки. axios - легко расширять для конкретного приложения, создавая свой собственный экземпляр.

**Используйте axios с vue везде, где это возможно**, особенно в отдельных приложениях на Vue/Vuex. Это будет еще один удобный инструмент в вашем арсенале.